# How to SORT the results from a database that are stored in a combo box

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, sorting, combobox

Demo: Click on the link below and select "Beginner". You'll note that the following quizzes that load in the combo-box are not sorted. This is the issue:

http://www.teachyourselfpython.com/testandtrack/

I have the following combo box which is reading a list of quizzes from a database. I wish for the results in the combobox to be sorted (alphabetically, for instance).

The layout / functionality is that the user FIRST selects a level (Beginner, Intermediate or Advanced). It then generates another combobox underneath it, from which the user can select a QUIZ. IT is these quizzes that need to be in sorted order, but at the moment they are being displayed in CREATION order.

I have looked this up but cannot seem to find an answer.

**My code is:**

```
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
    <?php include("nav.php"); ?>

        <div id="head" align="center">
            <img src="img/typbanner.png" alt="www.teachyourselfpython.com" width=600 height=180 />
        </div>

        <div id="main_body" align="center">
            <h2>Time to try a <big><b>TEST!</b></big></h2>

            <form id="myForm" name="onlyForm" action="quiz.php" class="home"  method="POST">
                <select name="quiz_level" id="quiz_form" class="form-control">
                    <option disabled selected="true">-- Select The level of your Test --</option>
                    <option value="Beginner">Beginner</option>
                    <option value="Intermediate">Intermediate</option>
                    <option value="Advanced">Advanced</option>
                </select>
<select  class="form-control" name="quiz" id="got_quiz" style="display:none;"> <!--onchange="showUser(this.value)"-->
```

**The javascript part is as follows:**

```
<script>
   "use strict";

              $("#quiz_form").change(function () {
           /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */
           var allbooks = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
           var dataString = "level=" + allbooks; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

           $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
               type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
               url: "get-quiz-by-level.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
               dataType: "json",
               data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
               success: function success(result) {
                   /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
                   var option = "";
                   result.forEach(function (quiz, i) {
                       option += "<option value=\"" + quiz.id + "\">" + quiz.quiz_name + "</option>";
                       if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz != 0) {
                           $("#password").show();
                       } else if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz == 0) {
                           $("#password").hide();
                       }
                   });
                   $("#got_quiz").show().html(option);
               }
           });
       });
       $("#got_quiz").change(function () {
           /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */
           var allbooks = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
           var dataString = "quiz=" + allbooks; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */
           $.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
               type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
               url: "check_quiz_pass.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
               data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
               success: function success(result) {
                   /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
                   if (result == 0) {
                       $("#password").hide();
                   } else {
                       $("#password").show();
                   }
               }
           });
       });
```

Can someone suggest what I need to add, and more importantly WHERE in order to achieve the sorting effect in the combobox?

I found this on SO (below code) but cannot see how to apply it, as it's a slightly different case, with the quizzes only loading, AFTER the LEVEL has been selected.

```
  <option value="3">three</option>
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
<script>
  // WARN: won't handle OPTGROUPs!
  var sel = document.getElementById('foo');
  // convert OPTIONs NodeList to an Array
  // - keep in mind that we're using the original OPTION objects
  var ary = (function(nl) {
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = nl.length; i < len; i++)
      a.push(nl.item(i));
    return a;
  })(sel.options);
  // sort OPTIONs Array
  ary.sort(function(a,b){
    // sort by "value"? (numeric comparison)
    // NOTE: please remember what ".value" means for OPTION objects
    return a.value - b.value;
    // or by "label"? (lexicographic comparison) - case sensitive
    //return a.text < b.text ? -1 : a.text > b.text ? 1 : 0;
    // or by "label"? (lexicographic comparison) - case insensitive
    //var aText = a.text.toLowerCase();
    //var bText = b.text.toLowerCase();
    //return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
  });
  // remove all OPTIONs from SELECT (don't worry, the original
  // OPTION objects are still referenced in "ary") ;-)
  for (var i = 0, len = ary.length; i < len; i++)
    sel.remove(ary[i].index);
  // (re)add re-ordered OPTIONs to SELECT
  for (var i = 0, len = ary.length; i < len; i++)
    sel.add(ary[i], null);
</script>
```

Comment: Why not sort them in your database query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to sort by `quiz_name` property like this

```
result.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.quiz_name.localeCompare(b.quiz_name);
});
```

Insert it like this

```
$.ajax({ /* THEN THE AJAX CALL */
   type: "POST", /* TYPE OF METHOD TO USE TO PASS THE DATA */
   url: "get-quiz-by-level.php", /* PAGE WHERE WE WILL PASS THE DATA */
   dataType: "json",
   data: dataString, /* THE DATA WE WILL BE PASSING */
   success: function success(result) {

       /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
       var option = "";
       result
           .sort(function (a, b) {
               return a.quiz_name.localeCompare(b.quiz_name);
           })
           .forEach(function (quiz, i) {
               option += "<option value=\"" + quiz.id + "\">" + quiz.quiz_name + "</option>";
               if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz != 0) {
                   $("#password").show();
               } else if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz == 0) {
                   $("#password").hide();
               }
           });
       $("#got_quiz").show().html(option);
   }
});
```

Do not try to roll your own string comparison function, as you need to take into account casing (upper case/lower case), symbols and other fun stuff.

Comment: Genius, Thank You!

Comment: What do you mean by "roll your own string comparison function?"? Have you taken this into account in your answer? :)

Comment: I mean do not use `result.sort(function (a, b) { return a.quiz_name > b.quiz_name; });` or similar, since the [relational operators in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) compare the Unicode character codes when comparing strings. This does not provide the natural order that a human would expect. E.g. `'bar' < 'Baz' === false` so `'Baz'` would come before `'bar'`.

Comment: So instead of trying to account for all the edge cases, I rely on the standard `String` method of `localeCompare` to compare the `quiz_name` properties. This method is made exactly for use cases like this.

Comment: The function we pass into `Array#sort` is the *comparison function*. I.e. `result.sort(function comparisonFunction(a, b) { // Compare the two objects here });`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

```js
var array = [{
    password_quiz: "",
    quiz_name: "Z",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    password_quiz: "",
    quiz_name: "A",
    id: 2
  }
];

function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.quiz_name < b.quiz_name) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a.quiz_name > b.quiz_name) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

console.log("Unsorted");
console.log(array);
array.sort(compare);
console.log("Sorted");
console.log(array);
```

**You need to sort your array before this part of your code (`result.forEach(function (quiz, i) {...}`):**

```
function compare(a, b) {
  if (a.quiz_name < b.quiz_name) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (a.quiz_name > b.quiz_name) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}

result.sort(compare);

result.forEach(function (quiz, i) {
   option += "<option value=\"" + quiz.id + "\">" + quiz.quiz_name + "</option>";
   if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz != 0) {
       $("#password").show();
   } else if (i == 0 && quiz.password_quiz == 0) {
       $("#password").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you - can you explain where in my code I would need to add this. As mentioned, I can find things on the internet on how to sort a standalone combobox, but my issue is integrating into what I have now.

Comment: ..and see my update (which includes a link to a site with this issue)